# Dynamics 365 virtual entities from Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, dynamics-crm-365

The “[Azure Cosmos DB for DocumentDB API Data Provider](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dynamics-365/mscrm.documentdb_data_provider?flightCodes=InnovationDevelopment&tab=Overview)” does not seem to be actively maintained and I was not able to get it to work in D365 CE. I would like to use my Cosmos TB to be the source for some virtual entities in my CRM and the only way I can get this to work is writing a data provider plugin or creating an api. Is anyone aware of any other method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to expose your database or
Particular table as Odata v4.0 webapi.
Or you could create your own data provider and expose your data through that data provider.

This is how data shall be available in virtual entity.
Note: your odata or custom data provider should respect field types of Crm.
For ex: 1 mandatory EDM.Guid field and so
On.

Comment: I have openend a support ticket with Microsoft and have been communicating with them since August but the dev team was not able to solve this issue. It seems that the Cosmos api has changed over time and the solution was never updated. They tried impress me once with increasing version number but a binary compare of the assemblies indicated no changes in the actual code.